# Complete checkout for Rs.0 product in shopify android

Tags: android, shopify

I want to complete checkout in Shopify android.
I have applied 100% discount coupon code, checkout object is created but getting this error-

{"errors":{"checkout":{"payment_gateway":[{"code":"invalid","message":"is invalid","options":{}}]}}}

I have passed Empty Payment token.
What should i pass in Payment token field  ??
I am using this method-
  CancellableTask completeCheckout(PaymentToken paymentToken, String               checkoutToken, Callback callback);

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a direct credit card gateway enabled on your shop (i.e. not an offsite payment gateway)? The Mobile Buy SDK is only compatible with direct payment gateways.

Comment: how to check that thing??